# Crossfade image view on Android not resetting - same image being clicked

Tags: java, android

I am trying to write an app to crossfade between two images and then back when clicked.
The initial method, `fade`, works fine and fades to the new image, but when the second image is clicked, there is no effect.
I think the problem is that the first image is still overlayed on the second, so that I am just clicking the first image over and over.
However I added printing the `hashcode()` of the image variables to check the execution and it appears to be returning the same variables from only method`fadeBack` each time.
I have annotated in the logs (`// n click on image n`) which entries appeared on each click, but it seems the same method is being called, `fadeBack`, when `fade` should be being called.

Any more information needed, please let me know.

Logs:

```
12-29 19:02:22.273 15746-15746/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
12-29 19:02:22.566 15746-15746/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo-2/lib/x86
12-29 19:02:22.842 15746-15757/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 22155(972KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 16MB/16MB, paused 14.211ms total 68.404ms
12-29 19:02:22.871 15746-15757/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo W/art: Suspending all threads took: 29.427ms
12-29 19:02:22.905 15746-15757/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo W/art: Suspending all threads took: 13.161ms
12-29 19:02:22.980 15746-15757/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 130(10KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 19% free, 16MB/20MB, paused 16.186ms total 106.877ms
12-29 19:02:23.014 15746-15757/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo W/art: Suspending all threads took: 33.481ms
12-29 19:02:23.018 15746-15767/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
12-29 19:02:23.138 15746-15767/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
12-29 19:02:23.192 15746-15767/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-29 19:02:23.192 15746-15767/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad7a0a80, error=EGL_SUCCESS
12-29 19:02:27.146 15746-15746/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/System.out: Hashcode in fadeBack - will: 176777760 //First click on image 1
12-29 19:02:27.146 15746-15746/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/System.out: Hashcode in fadeBack - obama: 261627865 //First click on image 1
12-29 19:02:30.197 15746-15746/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/System.out: Hashcode in fadeBack - will: 176777760 //Second click on image 2
12-29 19:02:30.197 15746-15746/com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo I/System.out: Hashcode in fadeBack - obama: 261627865 // //Second click on image 2
```

Code:

```
package com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView obama;
    ImageView will;

    public void fade(View view) {
        System.out.println("Hashcode in fade - will: " + will.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Hashcode in fade - obama: " + obama.hashCode());
        obama.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
        will.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);

    }

    public void fadeBack(View view) {
        System.out.println("Hashcode in fadeBack - will: " + will.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Hashcode in fadeBack - obama: " + obama.hashCode());
        will.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
        obama.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        obama = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obama);
        will = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.will);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Activity Main xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:clickable="false">

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/obama"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:src="@drawable/obama"
         android:onClick="fade" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/will"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/obama"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:src="@drawable/will"
        android:alpha="0"
        android:onClick="fadeBack" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out.
As the drawable, `will` was on top of `obama` in the design, the `fadeBack` method was always being called. 
Changed the code so that the crossfade and return was contained in one method, with a counter to control which way it went.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView obama;
    ImageView will;
    int count;

    public void fade(View view) {

        if (count == 0) {
            obama.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
            will.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
            count++;
        } else {
            will.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(2000);
            obama.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(2000);
            count = 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        obama = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.obama);
        will = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.will);
        count = 0;

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.richardcurteis.layoutdemo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    android:clickable="false">

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/obama"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
         android:src="@drawable/obama"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/will"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/obama"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/will"
        android:onClick="fade"
        android:alpha="0" />
</RelativeLayout>
```